# Constructing output filename from input filename + suffix in python loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, filenames

I am new to python and currently facing a problem, that is probably easy to solve. I am using a for loop to iteratively do calculations on a larger number of input files. The loop is working but as I am producing four different output files that contain different kinds of results from one input I would like to save the output file as (input_filename) + (_result) + (.extension). For example, if my input file is called '1sl4.pdb' I would like to have the output as: '1sl4_gnm_zs.csv'. Anyone has a good idea to solve this? Any help is appreciated!

Best,
Jonathan

My code looks like this:

```
#packages
from prody import *
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path

ion()

# assign directory
pdb_directory = '/home/lefebrej95/Documents/PDB'

data_essa = []

# iterate
for f in os.listdir(pdb_directory):
    if f.endswith('.pdb'):  # select file that ends with pdb

        atoms = parsePDB(pdb_directory + '/' + f)
        essa = ESSA()
        essa.setSystem(atoms)
        essa.scanResidues()

        essa.getESSAZscores()
###safe data to .npy
        essa.saveESSAZscores()
###safe data to .csv
        essa.saveESSAZscorestoCSV()
       
        plt.clf()

        with style.context({'figure.dpi': 100}):
            essa.showESSAProfile()
###safe plot to .png
            plt.savefig()
            plt.show()
            
###safe data to .pdb
        essa.writeESSAZscoresToPDB()
```

Comment: `out_file = f'{f[:-4]}_{result}.{ext}'` where `result` is your test method and `ext` is your extension? For example `f = '1sl4.pdb'` `result = 'gnm_zs'` `ext = 'csv'` and `out_file = f'{f[:-4]}_{result}.{ext}'` would make `out_file` a string with the value `'1sl4_gnm_zs.csv'`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. However, I have figured out an 'easier' way. My question was not well formulated as it was missing some info. What I wanted to have in my filename was to include the input file name and the 'type of result' and the method. I now solved this by using f strings. such as: 

`plt.savefig('{}_{}_zs.png'.format(essa._title, essa._enm), transparent=True)`